# Extend connector with polarity keys (14 pins, 2 rows of 7 aligned pins)

Tags: connector

I need to build and extension cable for this connector.

It is a 14 pined (2 rows of 7 aligned pins). The cables have a diameter of 1mm, and the connector has 1 key on each side, and 2 keys at the top (which is impossible to see in the image below because the camera could not focus). Those keys are there to make sure you connect the connector the right way, because the male terminal has holes to ensure the cables are fitted correctly.

I tried searching for JST connectors but I haven't found any 14 pinned JST connector. It seems like a dupont connector but the keys on each side and at the top were not present in the examples that I have seen.

How can extend this connector? Should I buy a regular dupont connector and "hack my way around those keys? Any guidance will be highly appreciated

[image: connector]

Comment: I recommend calling these lumps "polarity keys" or just "keys." Also, what is the pitch (space between pins), as that is of primary importance in finding a matching connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a JST PHDR-14VS connector

https://www.conrad.com/p/jst-phdr-14vs-housing-phd-series-number-of-pins-2-x-7-nominal-current-details-3-a-740156

The pitch is 2.00mm, so standard breadboard wires will be bigger (2.54mm). I tested with some breadboard wires and they fit the female side but not the male side.

Comment: I would add the manufacturer link (or use it exclusively) in the event that the distributor stops carrying the part. https://www.jst.com/products/crimp-style-connectors-wire-to-board-type/phd-connector/ and datasheet: https://www.jst.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/ePHD.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Finding connectors is a chore even for the experienced. Here are some tips to help you find the right one:

This type of connector is usually called a "rectangular connector" and come in a few main categories such as "wire-to-board" and "board-to-board."

The one you have pictured appears to be on the end of a cable, but it's hard to tell. What you probably want is a **female (socket) rectangular connector in the wire-to-board category.**

The most important things you will need to specify are:

- **pin pitch** (space between pins; yours looks like it could be a very common 2.54 mm (0.1 in)
- **number of pins** (some manufacturers only care about the count of one row, so be careful)
- **number of rows**
- **pitch between rows** can be separately specified (yours appears to be the same as the pin pitch)

The "lumps" are polarity keys, sometimes just called "keys" but can be referred to in a number of colloquial ways such as tabs, slots, guides, etc. It's most common to have a single wide polarity key centered on a long edge on these ribbon-style connectors. You may have to do some extra searching to find the specific version you have, and it's possible it is proprietary.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance. I ended up finding this after a 4 day google grind.